# RStudio: After "Install and Restart", the functions of an R package are not found

Tags: r, github, build, package, rstudio

I have started a new project in RStudio and by connecting to a GitHub repository. Then I turned the RStudio project into an R package with [`usethis::create_package()`](https://r-pkgs.org/whole-game.html#create_package).

Everything seems ok. However, after I [*"Install and Restart"*](https://r-pkgs.org/whole-game.html#install) the project and attach the package (`library( mypackage )`), the functions in the package can not be found (RStudio does not complete typing, and an explicit call raises an error). Instead, I have to first call [`devtools::load_all()`](https://r-pkgs.org/whole-game.html#whole-game-load-all).

The *"Install and Restart"* command in RStudio produces the following:

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source mypackage

* installing to library 'path-to-r'
* installing *source* package 'mypackage' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
No man pages found in package  'mypackage' 
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (mypackage)
```

After the restart, RStudio calls `library( mypackage )`

Could it be that calling `create_package()` for an existing project, does not create all the necessary settings (what might they be?)? When start by creating an R package in RStudio (and create a repository from the existing project), all functions can be found after build (as they should).

Comment: did you call `library(yourpackagenamehere)`?

Comment: Yes, does not help.

Comment: Maybe try `devtools::install()` the package? Then `library(yourpackagenamehere)`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, RStudio installs the package after build..? (I updated the question with the build information)

Comment: RStudio does not install the package automatically after building it.  You need to install it manually.  Also, your `build` output suggests that your package would fail `devtools::check()`.  Did you run `check()`?  If so, what did it report?  Building and installing a package is a long, time consuming process.  Don't embark on it lightly...

Comment: Thanks @Limey, I did no know that. What do the first lines (`installing...`) refer to then..? However, as I mentioned, when I have started from creating an R package, the functions can be found after build.

Comment: You've had two suggestions to install the package, but you are still arguing about whether you need to install the package. If you are unwilling to consider help, why ask for help?

Comment: I'm willing to consider help and already trying it out. I'm also trying to understand what all this means, and why it has worked differently before. If I run `devtools::install("mypackage")` or `devtools::check("mypackage")`, I get an error: `[ENOENT] Failed to realize 'mypackage': no such file or directory`

Comment: Now I understand that I have been actually installing the package, not yet building it (I thought that it would have been built first). I'll update the question.

Comment: "If I run ... devtools::check("mypackage"), I get an error": this strongly suggests to me that your set up for building the package is incorrect in some fundamental way.  Based on the information you've given here, I have no idea what the issue might be.  [Hadley's guide to package building](https://r-pkgs.org/) is a very useful resource.  I suggest you start over with a clean RStudio project, use `usethis::create_package()` to set up the infrastructure, and then import your existing code (following the guidelines in the link above) and use `devtools::check` frequently to assess your progress.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Limey. That's what I'll do. The reason I have done in the described order, is that in RStudio it is much more straightforward to first create a repository in Github and connect that to a new project, than to create a (R package) project and use that to create a repository (especially if the repository should be private and reside inside an organization/team).